# SFP LC to LC path code recommendation

Tags: fiber, sfp

I need to connect to Ubiquiti (router > Switch) using SFP.

I believe I need a Ubiquiti Networks UF-SM-1G-S transmitter (BiDi).

the cable will be around 40M long and crossing the house, underneath the doors and running in the hall way.

I initially though about 0.9mm (900um) as it very small and won't be an issue to go under the door, but realistically it's not possible, that's gonna break right away.

- Would you think 2.0mm will be alright ?
- would you recommend APC or UPC?

(unless I'm wrong I need LC-LC Simplex Single Mode Fibre Patch Lead)

Thank in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You can ask about that on [su].

Comment: That actually for the office with need a dedicated network

Comment: It is still a residential network, not a professionally managed network as explained in the [help/on-topic]: "_**Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment.**_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 40 m, 1000BASE-SX is the normal choice (that'd be UF-MM-1G), using a pair (duplex) of OM2/3/4 multi-mode fiber. MMF uses a 50 µm core.

The UF-SM-1G-S is for single-strand (simplex), single-mode fiber (9 µm core) and much more expensive, yet usable as well.

Which outer diameter your fiber has doesn't matter for indoor use. However, going under doors is a bad idea as especially thin fiber won't last long. You'll need a duct or a pipe to run the fiber through and you'll need to drill the walls.

APC is only required for passive optical networks (PON) to decrease the reflection from unterminated ports. For normal use, SPC/UPC is fine.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose I have to keep my ethernet cable for now then.